# OnePageScroll plugin - Trigger an event on scroll

Tags: jquery, events, scroll, bind, addclass

I am using the javascript plugin onePage (http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/onepage_scroll_demo.html) and I would like to fire an action only when a specific section is active.

As the plugin add the class 'active' to the section which becomes active, I thought of using this code but it doesn't work:

```
$('#mySection').bind("addClass",function(){
  alert( "my section becomes active" );
});
```

How can I make this work?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `afterMove` callback to check whether the section you want has become active. The onePage plugin adds an "active" class to the current section.

http://jsfiddle.net/JepzT/1/

```
$(".main").onepage_scroll({
   sectionContainer: "section",
   animationTime: 1000,
   pagination: true,
   updateURL: false,
   beforeMove: function (index) {},
   afterMove: function (index) {
       if ($('#mySection').hasClass('active')) {
           alert('My section has become active');
       }
   },
   loop: false,
   responsiveFallback: false
});
```

Comment: if I want to use the callback beforeMove, how can I get the section which is going to be display?

Comment: The plugin doesn't make it super-easy. Best way is to use a little setTimeout trick: http://jsfiddle.net/JepzT/2/